# Removing certain events from an unsorted table of events based on time, id and type of event

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

**TL;DR**: I am trying to remove repetitions of a certain type of events from an incoming list of events. I have 5-20 million records. Indented lines should be removed:

```
sn#     time        mo  method
02848   1504725241  R   P
02848   1504725365  R   F1.0
    02848   1504725366  R   F1.6
    02848   1504725366  R   F2.0
02848   1504727651  R   P
02848   1504727681  R   P
02848   1504727741  R   F1.0
02848   1504728165  R   E
```

### Long description:

To give some context, these are user actions performed. Where the mode is what type of service the user is using. And the method is what the user does. For example, P is short for pause, and F is short for fast forward.

The table I am working on has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE events
([serialnumber] int, [time] int, [mode] varchar(1), [method] varchar(4))
```

It is updated hourly with anywhere between 5 to 20 millions records.
With example data as seen above.

I wish to create sessions to fill in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions(serialnumber int, mode varchar(1), method varchar(1), startTime int, endTime int);
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create sessions based on these events, with one important filter. I don't want repetitions of events with method **F**, I just want the first **F** event, connected to whatever non **F** event comes next. That is, for the above I would like to have the following sessions after processing, i.e my desired result is:

```
#sn   metho mod starttime   endtime
02848   R   P   1504725241  1504725365
02848   R   F   1504725365  1504727651
02848   R   P   1504727651  1504727681      
02848   R   P   1504727681  1504727741  
02848   R   F   1504727741  1504728165
```

Here F1.0, F1.6, F2.0, etc. have been changed to F, the first timestamp of a group of F events remains, and repetitions have been removed. Because of the large number of records, I am having trouble doing this efficiently.

As of right now I am trying the following:

1. When the table is updated, remove all **F** events, except the first in every group of **F** events, pr serial number.
2. Use `cross apply` much like an `LAG` function to generate a list of sessions.

The full SQL code for this, looks like this:

```
--Delete recurring F events
DELETE outside
FROM events AS outside
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 inside.[Time]
  FROM events inside
  WHERE outside.serialnumber = inside.serialnumber
    AND (outside.[Time] > inside.[Time] 
     OR (outside.[Time] = inside.[Time] 
      AND outside.[method] != inside.[method]
      )
    )
    AND LEFT(outside.[method],1)  = 'F' 
    AND LEFT(inside.[method],1) = 'F'
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT innerInside.[Time] FROM events innerInside
      WHERE innerInside.serialnumber = inside.serialnumber
        AND innerInside.[Time] <= outside.[Time]
        AND innerInside.[Time] > inside.[Time]
        AND LEFT(innerInside.[method],1)  != 'F'
  )
  ORDER BY inside.[Time] DESC
) processed_inside


--Create sessions from events
SELECT serialnumber
      ,outside.[mode]
      ,LEFT(outside.[method],1) AS 'Method'
      ,outside.[Time] AS 'SessionStart'
      ,processed_inside.[Time] AS 'SessionEnd'

FROM events AS outside
CROSS APPLY
     (
      SELECT MIN( inside.[Time]) AS 'Time'
      FROM   events AS inside
      WHERE  outside.serialnumber = inside.serialnumber
         AND outside.[Time] < inside.[Time]
      ) processed_inside
WHERE processed_inside.[Time] IS NOT NULL
```

This works, but the deletion step is **unbearably slow**. Here is a picture of the actual execution plan for the deletion step.
[image]
(Note this is the actual database so it looks slightly different than the simplified examples in this post.)

I have also considered doing step 1 as part of step 2, but have not found any meaningful way to do so. In the end I am looking for a way to create sessions efficiently without generating too many sessions (hence removing events of type F).

If you made it all the way here, sqlfiddle can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5392/1. Where I have added both of the above functions. The output table is the desired result.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Are there no indexes?

Comment: to the ones who made edits to question: pls read text: he wanted give evidence to "indented lines"

Comment: @SqlZim No, but I could create them, as long as the `BULK INSERT` done to create the table, does not become slower than the operations I need to perform.

Comment: @ewolden : do you need delete of events or you just used to solve your problem?  I mean, if one can generate "sessions" as requested without deleting events, is it good for you?

Comment: @etsa If you could generate the sessions without deletion that would be perfect.

Comment: @ewolden you could be pls put desired result in your question (based on sample data you put on sqlfiddle, at least for serial 02848)?

Comment: @etsa I updated the fiddle in the post now, and some wording. The second table in the post is the desired result. But the fiddle now also shows the desired result.

Comment: So,     (02848, 1504728208, 'T', 'F1.0'), should be maintained after (02848, 1504728193, 'T', 'F1.0'),   ?  You'll have in this case two consecutive Fs?

Comment: Whoops, no, that is not how it is supposed to be. I have been too worried over performance to check the output thoroughly. Sorry.

Comment: @ewolden: the first F is always 'F1.0'?

Comment: @etsa yes, we can assume so.

Comment: @ewolden and the last F in a sequence would never be 'F1.0'?  So why don't filter the records using this rule?  I'm trying some things, but (using MSSQL2005 as you asked)  this could be a good starting point to simplify the query I'm trying to do...

Comment: While assuming the first is always 'F1.0', you can't assume the last is never 'F1.0'. Imagine pressing fast forward on a remote, the first time you press it is 2x speed, then 4x  speed then 8x speed. This is much the same, so if you fast forwarded too far, and want to go back you may end up with this sequence: F1.0, F1.6, F2.0, F4.0, F2.0, F1.6, F1.0, F-1.0, F1.0. But using 'F1.0' as a starting point is definitely a good idea that I have not explored.

Comment: I have an alternative that is around 3 orders of magnitude faster across 3 million records, but it returns identical results compared to your fiddle. If your output is not correct, then my alternative won't be helpful. (specifically referring to the `1504728208` issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Second update 20171009 15:35**

This should cope with all your sample data.
Some explanation about add-on to previous version:

- last condition in Q1 query (OR (RN=1 AND method='F') is to leave last
  F (since this latter is useful to compute endtime for aggregated F);
- in Q11 I used the two ROW_NUMBER() to find consecutive methods and
  in the WHERE condition are excluded consecutive Fs other than    the
  last one if present)
- in last query (Q2) inside WITH, endtime is computed using (SELECT TOP
  1 ....)
- the last WHERE condition is to remove (if present) an ending (but
  already cumulated) F method (see point 1 above)
- see what I said in previous versions too.

---

```
WITH Q1 AS (SELECT * 
                        FROM (SELECT serialnumber, [time] AS TTIME, mode, LEFT(method,1) AS method, SUBSTRING(method,2,3) AS rest_of_method
                                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber ORDER BY [time] DESC) AS RN
                              FROM events
                            )A
                              WHERE method<>'F' OR rest_of_method='1.0' OR (RN=1 AND method='F') 
                              /* AND serialnumber=6363*/  /* test*/             
                        )
            , Q11 AS (SELECT Q1a.serialnumber, Q1a.mode, Q1a.method, Q1a.starttime, RN
                      FROM (SELECT serialnumber, mode, method, TTIME AS starttime
                            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber ORDER BY TTIME, method) AS consec_id1    
                            , RN            
                            FROM Q1) Q1a 
                            LEFT JOIN   (SELECT serialnumber, mode, method, TTIME AS starttime
                                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber ORDER BY TTIME, method) AS consec_id2
                                        FROM Q1) Q1b on Q1b.serialnumber=Q1a.serialnumber AND Q1b.consec_id2 = Q1a.consec_id1 - 1
                      WHERE (Q1b.consec_id2 IS NULL
                            OR Q1a.method<>'F'
                            OR Q1a.method <> Q1b.method                 
                            OR RN=1) 
                    )
            , Q2 AS (SELECT Q11.serialnumber
                    , Q11.mode
                    , Q11.method
                    , Q11.starttime
                    , (SELECT TOP 1 starttime FROM Q11 Q2 WHERE Q2.starttime>Q11.starttime AND Q2.SERIALNUMBER=Q11.SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY Q2.starttime) AS endtime
                    , RN
                    FROM Q11
                     )
            SELECT Q2.serialnumber, Q2.mode, Q2.method, Q2.starttime, Q2.endtime
            FROM Q2
            WHERE NOT (method='F' AND endtime IS NULL)
            ORDER BY Q2.serialnumber, Q2.starttime;
```

Output:

```
serialnumber mode method starttime   endtime
------------ ---- ------ ----------- -----------
2848         R    P      1504725241  1504725365
2848         R    F      1504725365  1504727651
2848         R    P      1504727651  1504727741
2848         R    F      1504727741  1504728165
2848         R    E      1504728165  1504728167
2848         L    B      1504728167  1504728171
2848         T    B      1504728171  1504728193
2848         T    P      1504728171  1504728193
2848         T    F      1504728193  1504728208
2848         L    B      1504728208  1504728215
2848         T    E      1504728208  1504728215
2848         T    F      1504728208  1504728215
2848         L    B      1504728215  1504728221
2848         L    B      1504728221  1504728225
2848         L    B      1504728225  1504728230
2848         L    B      1504728230  1504728234
2848         L    B      1504728234  1504728238
2848         L    B      1504728238  1504728249
2848         L    B      1504728249  1504728255
2848         L    B      1504728255  1504728300
2848         L    B      1504728300  1504728845
2848         S    S      1504728845  1504728846
2848         S    S      1504728846  NULL
6363         R    B      1504726264  1504726265
6363         R    F      1504726265  1504729288
6363         R    E      1504729288  1504729289
6363         L    B      1504729289  1504729318
6363         R    B      1504729318  1504731181
6363         R    F      1504729318  1504731181
53344        L    B      1504725984  1504725987
53344        L    B      1504725987  1504725988
53344        L    B      1504725988  1504725992
53344        L    B      1504725992  1504725993
53344        L    B      1504725993  NULL
78901        L    B      1504725485  1504725488
78901        L    B      1504725488  1504725491
78901        L    B      1504725491  NULL
```

**Update 20171009 -- works only for 2848 at moment**

I modified previous query (see bottom) to solve the requisite of consecutive F1.0, Fx.xx,.., F1.0 (id est, you can start and end with F1.0 a sequence of Fs).
I think that if one day you will migrate to MSSQL2008+ it's possible to find a better solution.  Following should work on MSSQL2005.

*About performance:* 
I added PK to your dataset (EVENTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (serialnumber, mode, method, [time]), I added an index (INDEX EVENTS_IXN01 ON EVENTS (SERIALNUMBER, TIME)).

Actually, with your sample data, my query use index EVENTS_IXN01 only (but if you don't create PK I think you should include some columns into it).
I think some other improvements could be done (eg. if you split first letter of method from the rest).
Other improvements can be obtained if you decide to query only for some time windows (in this case you need to change/create index)

```
WITH Q1 AS (SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT serialnumber, [time] AS TTIME, mode, LEFT(method,1) AS method      
                  FROM events
                  WHERE (LEFT(method,1)<>'F' OR SUBSTRING(method,2,3)='1.0')
                  AND serialnumber=02848 /* test*/
                )A
            )
, Q2 AS (SELECT Q1.serialnumber
        , Q1.mode
        , Q1.method
        , Q1.TTIME AS starttime
        , (SELECT TOP 1 TTIME FROM Q1 Q2 WHERE Q2.TTIME>Q1.TTIME AND Q2.SERIALNUMBER=Q1.SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY Q2.TTIME) AS endtime
    FROM Q1
            )
SELECT Q4.serialnumber
        ,Q4.mode
        ,Q4.method
        ,Q4.starttime 
        ,Q4.endtime     
FROM (
    SELECT Q2.serialnumber
        ,Q2.mode
        ,Q2.method
        ,Q2.starttime 
        ,Q2.endtime+COALESCE(Q3.endtime-Q3.starttime,0) AS endtime
        ,Q3.starttime AS dupF_starttime
    FROM Q2
    LEFT JOIN Q2 Q3 ON Q2.serialnumber=Q3.serialnumber AND Q2.mode=Q3.mode AND Q2.method=Q3.method AND Q2.endtime=Q3.starttime AND Q2.method='F'
    ) Q4
WHERE dupF_starttime IS NULL
ORDER BY serialnumber, starttime;
```

Output

```
serialnumber mode method starttime   endtime
------------ ---- ------ ----------- -----------
2848         R    P      1504725241  1504725365
2848         R    F      1504725365  1504727651
2848         R    P      1504727651  1504727741
2848         R    F      1504727741  1504728165
2848         R    E      1504728165  1504728167
2848         L    B      1504728167  1504728171
2848         T    B      1504728171  1504728193
2848         T    P      1504728171  1504728193
2848         L    B      1504728208  1504728215
2848         T    E      1504728208  1504728215
2848         T    F      1504728208  1504728215
2848         L    B      1504728215  1504728221
2848         L    B      1504728221  1504728225
2848         L    B      1504728225  1504728230
2848         L    B      1504728230  1504728234
2848         L    B      1504728234  1504728238
2848         L    B      1504728238  1504728249
2848         L    B      1504728249  1504728255
2848         L    B      1504728255  1504728300
2848         L    B      1504728300  1504728845
2848         S    S      1504728845  1504728846
2848         S    S      1504728846  NULL
6363         R    B      1504726264  1504726265
6363         R    F      1504728525  1504729288
6363         R    E      1504729288  1504729289
6363         L    B      1504729289  1504729318
6363         R    B      1504729318  1504729334
6363         R    F      1504730579  NULL
53344        L    B      1504725984  1504725987
53344        L    B      1504725987  1504725988
53344        L    B      1504725988  1504725992
53344        L    B      1504725992  1504725993
53344        L    B      1504725993  NULL
78901        L    B      1504725485  1504725488
78901        L    B      1504725488  1504725491
78901        L    B      1504725491  NULL
```

**Previous**

This is not a definitive answer.  It's the only way I found to post it.

It doesn't respect the point you observed in comment ("While assuming the first is always 'F1.0', you can't assume the last is never 'F1.0'").

At moment (I have to leave now) I assumed that in a sequence of Fs the F1.0 cannot be repeated (I know, it's not what you are asking).
So I used only for serial number 02848 (where I removed the line     (02848, 1504728208, 'T', 'F1.0') from your sample data on SQLFiddle).

Maybe Monday I can continue to work on the query or maybe it can suggest you something.

```
WITH Q1 AS (SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT serialnumber, [time] AS TTIME, mode, LEFT(method,1) AS method      
                  FROM events
                  WHERE 1=1
                  AND (LEFT(method,1)<>'F' OR SUBSTRING(method,2,3)='1.0')
                  AND serialnumber=02848 /* test*/
                )A
            )
SELECT Q1.serialnumber
    , Q1.mode
    , Q1.method
    , Q1.TTIME AS starttime
    , (SELECT TOP 1 TTIME FROM Q1 Q2 WHERE Q2.TTIME>Q1.TTIME AND Q2.SERIALNUMBER=Q1.SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY Q2.TTIME) AS endtime
FROM Q1
ORDER BY Q1.serialnumber, Q1.TTIME
;
```

I saw a performance improvement using (but I could not do many other tests):

```
CREATE INDEX EVENTS_IXN01 ON EVENTS (SERIALNUMBER, TIME);
```

Output:

```
serialnumber mode method starttime   endtime
------------ ---- ------ ----------- -----------
2848         R    P      1504725241  1504725365
2848         R    F      1504725365  1504727651
2848         R    P      1504727651  1504727741
2848         R    F      1504727741  1504728165
2848         R    E      1504728165  1504728167
2848         L    B      1504728167  1504728171
2848         T    B      1504728171  1504728193
2848         T    P      1504728171  1504728193
2848         T    F      1504728193  1504728208
2848         T    E      1504728208  1504728215
2848         L    B      1504728208  1504728215
2848         L    B      1504728215  1504728221
2848         L    B      1504728221  1504728225
2848         L    B      1504728225  1504728230
2848         L    B      1504728230  1504728234
2848         L    B      1504728234  1504728238
2848         L    B      1504728238  1504728249
2848         L    B      1504728249  1504728255
2848         L    B      1504728255  1504728300
2848         L    B      1504728300  1504728845
2848         S    S      1504728845  1504728846
2848         S    S      1504728846  NULL
```

Comment: This looks promising, and sparks a few ideas for me. I am likewise away until Monday. Will report back on how this performs and if I find a way to eliminate subsequent 'F1.0' from appearing in the result. Thank you!

Comment: @ewolden -- added another query version, which "remove" subsequent F1.0.  Added some notes on performances.

Comment: @ewolden  --- added another (3rd) version: it should work as requested (performance are a bit worst than previous...)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the time and effort spent. I really appreciate it. I have used your last iteration and am seeing a huge improvement in efficiency. Again, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.  Keep in mind that if one day you all migrate to SQLServer2008+,  query could be simplified.